# Wavelength to RGB

Tags: homework-and-exercises, visible-light, wavelength

I don't know how to convert $xyz$ chromaticity coordinates in sRGB. 
For example in [What {R,G,B} values would represent a 445nm monochrome lightsource color on a computer monitor?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94375/)
the author takes:

$$xyz = (0.145945, 0.045217, 0.808838) \rightarrow RGB = (1.47450, -178.21694, 345.59392)$$

But when I use the transfer matrix cited on wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRGB) I find:

$$xyz = (0.145945, 0.045217, 0.808838) \rightarrow RGB = (0.000155,-0.023021, 0.854036)$$
In 8 bit, I have $RGB =(0.04,-5.9,217.8)$.
So, it's very différent!

Is it possible to explain step by step to detect my mistake?

Comment: FWIW: The colors of many (most?) pure monochrome light sources lie outside of the _[color gamut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamut)_ of an RGB monitor. What you're actually looking for is the RGB triplet most closely _approximates_ the color of the given pure wavelength. The colors that a monitor can reproduce, in general will be slightly less _[saturated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness)_ than pure monochrome colors.